# what is the purpose of helper.basepath in angular ui route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

I was searching about helper.basepath in angular ui routing, and the unique information about that was it is a helper corresponds to the RouteHelperProvider, but thats all... So, what is its purpose?

In the code below what is the difference if a use

**templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'** /
**templateUrl: 'helper.resolveFor(dashboard.html)'**

```
state('app.dashboard', {
          url: '/dashboard',
          title: 'Dashboard',
          templateUrl: helper.basepath('dashboard.html'),
          resolve: helper.resolveFor('flot-chart','flot-chart-plugins', 'weather-icons')
      })
```

Comment: What is `helper`? I don't think it has anything to do with `ui-router`.

Answer (score 0):

helper is just the parameter name assigned to the RouteHelpersProvider that is defined in app.js and passed into App.config. Search for "App.provider('RouteHelpers'" or just RouteHelpers and you'll find where the basepath and resolveFor functions are defined. You should be able to determine what it's doing from there.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge basepath provides a layout for the page which can be reused in multiple pages and can be wait to resolve any other module. And the scope variables defined in the controller will be available   inside the basepath

```
.state('myroute', {
    url: '/my-route',
    templateUrl: RouteHelpersProvider.basepath('layout-template.html'),
    controller: 'myController',
    resolve: RouteHelpersProvider.resolveFor(<modules to be resolved before the route>)
})
```

The scope variabled defined in `MyController` will be available in `layout-template.html`.